# Session time out in cs page to use in my whole asp application

Tags: c#, asp.net, session-state

I need to give session time out for my web application. I have put session state in webconfig file in application

```
 <sessionState mode="InProc" cookieless="false" timeout="1"></sessionState>
```

And in cs page should i need to call any method to function this session state and i need to work this session state to my whole application. Pls help me what i need to put in cs page.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to do anything in the pages if you don't want to. Add a `Global.asax` file to your project (if you don't have one yet) and look for the `Session_End` method. It should look like this:

```
void Session_End(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    // Code that runs when a session ends. 
    // Note: The Session_End event is raised only when the sessionstate mode
    // is set to InProc in the Web.config file. If session mode is set to StateServer 
    // or SQLServer, the event is not raised.

}
```

You can have whatever logic you need in here to redirect, give a message to the users, do some database changes, etc...

Note: This will apply for your entire Asp.Net application!

Good luck!

Comment: Escano can i add the redirect code of page here i.e.,  Response.Redirect("../users/userhomepage.aspx");

Comment: Escano but i am getting this message "Response is not available in this context." and its not redirecting..

Comment: @Nirmala You are right, I should have known that (sleepy). You will not be able to redirect like that from that method. Did you find any other way or would you like me to help you with another solution?

Answer (score 0):

No special functions needed in `cs` file. Once configured in `web.config` it applies to whole application and can be overridden in `cs` file if needed.